# Selectively restore data to iPhone from iTunes backup

Tags: iphone, restore

I was unable to find a solution online, so my question to the expert community is:

Can I restore only the health data to my iPhone from an iTunes backup?

Comment: Not without purchasing the apps [Dr Fone](https://drfone.wondershare.com/iphone-7/selectively-restore-itunes-backup-to-iphone-7.html) or [Decipher Tools](https://deciphertools.com/blog/selective-iphone-backup/). I've never used either software titles, nor do I endorse or promote the app developers.

Comment: Unfortunately installing apps is impossible due to the restrictions imposed by my employer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are signed into icloud on a iphone go to general, storage & Backup Usage, then you will see icloud /*Manage Storage* with a arrow to open it. You can see and set all you applications to be included or not in your cloud. You can set what you want to back up or erase backups. If you sign out of Icloud you will only see the storage options. The Health app is the only one that seems to be sneaky. I don't think you can delete it.